# Game development and e-reputation

Tags: europe, reputation

I am currently working as IT architect / tech expert.

In my free time, I have developed a few apps and made them available on stores. Some of these are utility apps, some of these are games. I've added links to those apps on my personal website.

I wonder if having games published under my name may hurt my e-reputation, as game development might not be considered a professional or mature hobby? I'm working **in Europe** where people might have a different view on this topic than in the U.S.

Maybe I should publish/reference these games anonymously, on another website?

Comment: Well so break your fears down into smaller chunks. If you like to make games and utility apps in your free time, and especially if you make money off your efforts, what are people *really* going to get on your case about? In your opinion?

Comment: `games are usually considered "not serious stuff"` - Really? Tell that to the companies that are making billions of dollars each year in the gaming industry.

Comment: @CKM joeqwerty Please note that this is in Europe where people have a slighter different view on this topic.  This is not in the U.S.

Comment: I'm in Switzerland and having successfully written and published games would certainly be a big plus for any candidate for a developer position I'm hiring for.

Comment: "In europe" is a rather broad description. Don't forget that you're talking about different countries with different cultures and laws.

Comment: The important question isn't whether these apps are games, it's whether they look crap or whether they look professional. And this applies to all of them, not just the games.

Answer (score 14):

Games are serious stuff.  Unless they've been badly received, then it makes sense to highlight these in your resume.

Be prepared, however, to discuss any coding techniques, frameworks, integrations and issues you overcame in designing and building these apps.

Don't shove these to the back of your resume and attempt to play them down, there's valuable code in them there games!

Comment: Why "Unless they've been badly received"? Even then, you probably learned something, be it a hard skill like C++ or a soft one like "what not to do if you're aiming for that audience".

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to keep your CV updated properly, with the relevant work. Employers usually care about the profit you can make for them.

I think it will not hurt to put this effort of yours into the CV. I would add it at the "Hobbies" section. Making "small" games can be considered a hobby.

If somebody looks intrigued by this "hobby", explain them how it keep your mind / brain focused and trained, while expanding the ways of thinking.

You are afraid that your games can be seen as a "damage". You should present them from the start as they are: a tool to train yourself, an additional technical skill.

Heck, if you are "brave" enough, you can even put it in the "Experience" section in your CV. Especially if you even make some money (amount may be irrelevant for the discussion, unless it helps you get rich).

Answer (score 0):

Games are seen as needing a high level of programming knowledge and especially structure and more abstract thinking about code and flow than something like enterprise applications so I would definitely highlight them in your CV.

Smaller ones may not grab much attention but if you have any medium size projects the code structure alone can be a big bonus point for anyone looking through your portfolio.

There's not really a stigma against game developers, at least in Europe, so there's no real reason for you to not include them.

Answer (score 0):

Games are highly technical, difficult-to-make software. The only way you could possibly damage your reputation is by going the way of Digital Homicide (create crappily put-together asset-flip games and falsely DMCA anyone who criticises you)

Just because it doesn't have a serious use doesn't mean that serious work doesn't go into making one. If anything it shows off your skills with the likes of C# (almost all available game engines use this as a scripting engine).

Comment: Another way to ruin yourself would be to create high quality games of very distasteful subjects - and tie your real name to them.

Comment: @PeterM Not necessarily, infact I can't think of a single example of this. Horror games do this the time, as does Rockstar North games. Even CoD has done this. (No Russian). Generally this will only hurt if controversy is the only thing selling your content (that school shooter Counter Strike ripoff comes to mind)

Comment: The school part *is* what I meant by distasetful.

Comment: @PeterM in which case it is less about the game being distasteful and more so the author (we all know the only reason they went with that setting was to market the game via shock and controversy)

Answer (score 0):

**The important question isn't whether these apps are games, it's whether they look crap or whether they look professional. This applies to all those apps! Games do not lower what people think of your qualifications. They might affect how good a cultural fit you are considered as though.**

"Looking crap" is possible by

- either visually looking totally outdated and done with outdated technology or UI design
- having lots of negative reviews, particularly regarding bugs
- being strongly associated with controversial topics, like extremist propaganda, or dealing with distasteful topics, like a game that only consists of literal crap pieces jumping around or with sexist, paedophile etc. topics.

Note that there is somewhat of a grey area with borderline cases especially with regard to the third point controversial topics. What's totally okay if you apply to one company might be a red flag to another company. So if in doubt, you may want to put those apps that go into a potentially controversial topic under a different name to keep your options as broad as possible and only reveal them, when you think that kind of topic/humour etc. is fine with the company you are applying too.

*Cultural Fit*:

There is one aspect in which the apps being games might influence how you are perceived: They might be used to gauge whether you fit the team. E.g. if you apply to a gaming company, they might be a big plus. If you apply to a very conservative company of family people, you might be considered as a bit of a gaming geek who still spends his time with games. Whether you would want to work in a company that considers being interested in games as a hobby a minus point, you have to decide yourself. I.e. if this is a criterium for how well a fit with the company you are then it might also a criterium how good a fit the company is for you...